# Indesign Grep Style Help needed for look behind and a head

Tags: grep, nested, adobe-indesign

Am working in **Indesign**. The idea is that a student can choose what word makes the sentence correct.
Want to use grep or nested styles to acchieve the following:

So i have a series of sentences where i want to have the latest word before a slash and the first word after the slash to be styled.

Example: This man makes / does an appointment

How can i use grep to style the words (makes and does) around the / (back slash) and make them bold.

- How to only select a word?
- I could try to find two spaces before and after the / forward slash

code i tried and got all my words before the slash in same style: ^.*?(/|$)

Hope you can help me out

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to match a word – and it mainly depends on what you call a "word". If it's anything not-whitespace, then you can use `\S+`. This will include ounctuation such as parentheses, apostrophes, comma's and full stops as well.
If it is a sequence of "word characters" (letters, digits, and, for historical reasons, the underscore), use `\w+`.
Any other custom sequence is possible as well with a custom character selection: `[-A-Za-z]+`, for example, will only include capital and lowercase latin characters and the hyphen.

For your purpose, you can use either of the above. It does not specifically *need* a lookbehind and lookahead. To match "word / word" all you need is `\w+ / \w+`; then apply a no-bold style (if there is a visible difference in that '/' alone) to just `/`.

But of course it can be done with both a lookahead and a lookbehind as well: `\w+(?= /)|(?<=/ )\w+` should work nicely:

[image: that GREP style at work on some example text]